# Spring mongo change stream checking for events very frequently

Tags: spring, mongodb, changestream

I have developed spring boot application with reactive mongo change stream. It’s working pretty well without any issues. But we found one issue with mongo change stream. In mongo compass performance tool I observed that query executing very frequently (less than a minute) without any changes happening in mongo collection. In my code I did not found any logs. I don’t know the what is issue. Could you please anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance.

I have tried with close the cursor. But no use.

Comment: What's your desired/preferred behavior here? You mention that you want to have an app that is reactive (which can be interpreted as responsive) to changes - the way the app via change streams accomplishes that is by continuously monitoring the system. It feels like you are describing expected behavior